# H2 In memory database inconsistent when using threads

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, h2

I've been sitting on this problem from several hours and am absolutely stumped as to what is going on.

Basically I am running a Swing Worker task in an ExecutorService thread pool and passing an in memory H2 database to test some database interactions. What's happening is a situation where I'm getting a referential integrity error *sometimes* as a result of inserting a SnapshotFV into the db when there needs to be a Snapshot inserted first.

Now if I break right before executing the threads, I can check the database and see that the Snapshot row does exist in the database, however if I break within in the doInBackground method on the line that produces the problem, that row no longer is in the database, even though the datasource object has the same object Id as before. The H2 database seeming to have reset at some point in the chain. It's hard to tell but it seems like it doesn't necessarily happen everytime when I debug, however it definitely happens everytime if I just run.

If I set the thread pool to 1, no problems.

During debugging I've checked all the object ID's to make sure nothing weird is happening with something getting set to null or something. The datasource and snapshot IDs are the same

```
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

    for (File f : files) {
         FVGatherer task = new FVGatherer(f, dataSource, snapshot);
         taskExecutor.execute(task);
    }

    taskExecutor.shutdown();
    try {
        taskExecutor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ...
    }


    ...


    private static class FVGatherer extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        private final File f;
        private final XDataSource dataSource;
        private final Snapshot snapshot;

        ...
        constructor
        ...

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            FV fv = getFV(f, dataSource);
            FI fi = getFI(f, dataSource);

            if (fv != null && fi != null) {
                SnapshotFV sfv = dataSource.createSnapshotFV(snapshot, fv, fi);
                snapshotFVs.add(sfv);
            }

            progressIncrementer.run();
            return null;
        }
```

The erorr:

> 13:25:20.021 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR JdbcUtilities - catching
>   org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: 
>   "FK_SNAPSHOTFV: PUBLIC.SNAPSHOTFV FOREIGN KEY(SNAPSHOT_ID)
>   REFERENCES PUBLIC.SNAPSHOT(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
>   insert into SNAPSHOTFV (SNAPSHOT_ID, FV_ID, FI_ID) values (?, ?, ?) [23506-175]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Another detail that I just noticed. The getFV and getFI also insert objects into the database and if I have thread pool set > 1 then then they as well seem to not show up in the database in the doInBackground method. Again, set the thread pool to 1 and break in the same place and the FV, FI, and snapshot appear in the database. Could it be that these methods are causing some exception or issue that is not being reported that invalidates and as a result resets the in memory database? I can post the code for these methods if requested.

**EDIT2**

Failing on line:

```
SnapshotFV sfv = dataSource.createSnapshotFV(snapshot, fv, fi);
```

Stack trace:

```
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:332) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:172) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:149) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:368) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:310) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:894) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:911) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:162) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:115) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:79) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:253) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:154) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:140) ~[h2-1.3.175.jar:1.3.175]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.jar:2.1]
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.jar:2.1]
at data.sources.JdbcUtilities.insertItem(JdbcUtilities.java:92) [bin/:?]
at data.sources.SnapshotFVSource.create(SnapshotFVSource.java:61) [bin/:?]
at data.PooledDataSource.createSnapshotFV(PooledDataSource.java:347) [bin/:?]
at util.SnapshotVersionUtil$FVGatherer.doInBackground(SnapshotVersionUtil.java:262) [bin/:?]
at util.SnapshotVersionUtil$FVGatherer.doInBackground(SnapshotVersionUtil.java:1) [bin/:?]
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_60]
```

**Edit 3**

This problem seems to only exist for me when using the in-memory database. A physical disc database seems to work. Hmm...

Comment: Could you post the rest of the stack trace?  What line is it failing on?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: If I understand this "connection should only be used in one thread at any time." correctly, h2 is not completely threadsafe. http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/jdbc/JdbcConnection.html

Comment: You may need to put your calls to your datasource in synchronized blocks.  I'm not familiar with h2 so I can't speak to it's thread safeness.  However, if you have multiple threads accessing datasource concurrently, it could cause issues.

Comment: @Marged the full statement "Thread safety: the connection is thread-safe, because access is synchronized. However, for compatibility with other databases, a connection should only be used in one thread at any time." seems to suggest that it is thread safe considering I'm only using 1 h2 database and no other database. Unless I misunderstand that statement.

Comment: Could you post the _complete_ error message, including error codes please?

Comment: @ThomasMueller updated post

Answer (score 2):

I still don't have a satisfying answer for this but I can only conclude that H2's in-memory database is not thread safe, whereas the disk database is thread safe.

Comment: Thomas Mueller should fix the issue and post back, it is a year has passed since then...